# Pipeline for commercial Android installation?

Tags: java, android, hardware

This might not be the right place for this but...

I am working on an Android app that will "take over" a piece of hardware. Basically the app would be the whole reason for the hardware. Picture a sensor with a screen, running on bespoke hardware with a custom android app to put data to a little screen.

How do people, like Motorola for instance, make hundreds and thousands of these things? Is there a set of "industrial tools" that make installing a custom ROM and APK a snap?

Comment: Unless you are assembling the bespoke hardware from parts yourself, the job of getting your Android ROM (with a pre-installed APK) on the bespoke hardware is usually the job of the firm assembling the bespoke hardware (e.g., Foxconn).

Comment: Got it. So the people who generate the hardware have some sort of final ROM that gets customized then pushed to each machine that they make. Are there tools to help on the ROM side? The stuff I find on the web pretty arcane and you have to read a ton of forum posts and things. It is not at all like developer documentation for instance.

Comment: "So the people who generate the hardware have some sort of final ROM that gets customized then pushed to each machine that they make" -- AFAIK, yes. "Are there tools to help on the ROM side?" -- I have no idea what sorts of tools you are expecting. "It is not at all like developer documentation for instance" -- correct, because it's a niche topic. There are [books on the subject](http://www.amazon.com/Embedded-Android-Porting-Extending-Customizing/dp/1449308295), FWIW.

Comment: Hey @CommonsWare, is there some way for me to give you "credit" for this answer?